# Bitrix Как вывеси элементы инфоблока по его категориям?

Tags: php, ajax, веб-программирование, битрикс

Есть задание вывести список новостей инфоблока по категориям. Страница должна состоять из:
Табов(кнопки переключения) с названием разделов, по нажатию на которые должны подгружаться элементы данного раздела на ajax. При этом в одном разделе могут находиться другие в следствие его при нажатии на родительский должны выводиться все элементы дочернего. У каждого элемента должна быть ссылка на подробную страница.
Я хочу получить совет о том как лучше это реализовать.

Comment: И при чем тут сортировка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете разделы в инфоблоке так как вам надо, на странице верстаете табы и блок для вывода данных, по нажатию на таб посылаете ajax-запрос, в котором передается id раздела (или код), который можно указать в data-атрибуте таба

(например `<a href='javascrip:void(0)' data-section=12>Название раздела</a>`).

Соответственно получить id: `$(a).data('section)`
В ответ на запрос передаете элементы из раздела (из дочерних разделов по идее должны подтянуться автоматически в выборке из раздела). Элементы можно передавать сразу в шаблоне либо распарсить уже в js-ке.

На будущее, обычно для табов сразу подтягиваются все данные, а при нажатии просто переключаются блоки, а ajax-ом тянутся данные, например если есть постраничная навигация или кнопка "Показать еще".

Comment: Вот чувак ещё один вопрос как реализовать ajax запрос для подгрузи элементов?

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Comment: Меня интересовало как  это сделать в битриксе

Comment: ajax он и в битриксе ajax, делается все точно также